# How to join four tables with hibernate

Tags: java, php, hibernate, laravel

I have a four tables which I need to join. These four tables  are:

1. product
2. service
3. service_type
4. service_duration

A product has a service, and a service has a type and duration.

The user chooses the product, the type, the service, and the duration of the service.

In the case that a service is not available for the chosen type and duration I would like to be able to get the service which has a type of lower priority (priority is attribute in the service_type table).

In php(Laravel) I am able to join like so:

```
DB::table('product')
        ->join('product_service', 'product_service.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
        ->join('service', 'service.id', '=', 'product_service.service_id')
        ->join('service_type', 'service.type_id', '=', 'service_type.id')
        ->join('service_duration', 'service.duration_id', '=', 'service_duration.id')
        ->where('product.id', id)
        ->where('service_type.priority', '<', priority)
        ->where('service_duration.duration', duration)
        ->where('maintenance.active', 1)
        ->orderBy('service_type.priority', 'desc')
        ->select('service.*')
        ->first();
```

How is it possible to do this with Hibernate Entity Criteria ? I want to start of by joining from the product side but in the end select the service.

I have my relations defined like so:

Product class

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "product")
 public class product implements Serializable {
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.product", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<ProductService> services = new HashSet<ProductService>();
  }
```

ProductService Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_service")
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "id.service", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "id.product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))})

public class ProductService  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductServicePK id = new ProductServicePK();


    @Column(name = "price")
    private Float price;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
}
```

ProductServicePK Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProductServicePK implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    private Service service;
}
```

Service class:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "service")
public class Service implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    private ServiceType type;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "duration_id")
    private ServiceDuration duration;
}
```

So the object that 'holds' reference to the other is the product object. So I am not sure how to get the service for that product which has a priority lower than the one selected.

I want to do this with criteria or HQL.

Comment: Yes you can do this. Are your Entity classes already setup with the `@OneToOne`/`@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne` relationships?

Comment: Hibernate documentation explains clearly how to work with relations. Did you take a look to Hibernate documentation ? [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)

Comment: @DeanClark yes, they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the JPA Criteria API does not support what I need when using the composite PK pattern. I found this mentioned somewhere [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html). So I found the best solution was using HQL:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select s "
            + "from Service s "
            + "join s.productService as ps "
            + "join s.type as t "
            + "where s.duration = :durationId "
            + "and ps.id.product.id = :productId "
            + "and t.priority <= :priorityValue "
            + "order by t.priority desc");
    q.setLong("durationId", durationId);
    q.setInteger("priorityValue", priorityValue);
    q.setLong("productId", productId);

    return (Service) q.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Hibernate Detached Criteria will like:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Product.class,     "product")
    .criteria.createAlias("product.product_service", "productService")
    .createAlias("productService.service","service")
    .createAlias("service.service_type","serviceType")
    .createAlias("service_duration","serviceDuration")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("product.id", id))
    .add(Restrictions.gt("serviceType.priority", priority))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("serviceDuration.duration", duration))
    .setProjection(add your productService projection here)
    getExecutableCriteria(session).SetMaxResults(1) ;
```

But i am not getting your point, why you are using `from query` on `product` instead of `product_service`?, because you need `product_service` details.

you can you use querycriteria.html, here is the doc of it->https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html 
or you can use hql ->https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html for achieve your result.

Comment: I don't mind if it happens the other way round just that I get the same result.

Comment: @user3552551 then you can use DetachedCriteria like as i have mention above.

Comment: I think I am starting from the product side because that is where the many to many relation is defined.  I will try your solution thanks.